# Why the reversibility requirement in Clausius equality doesn't prevent defining the entropy from it?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, reversibility

In his original work Clausius defines the entropy from his equality $\oint \frac{\delta Q}{T}=0$, which holds for a reversible cyclic process. As it means the integral $\int \frac{\delta Q}{T}$ over a reversible process depends only on the endpoints, it follows a state function $S$ may be found such that the integral equals $\Delta S$. From this if its value is fixed for any arbitrary reference equilibrium state then it's uniquely defined for any state reachable from reference via a reversible process by
$$
S(given)=S(ref)+\int_{ref}^{given}\frac{\delta Q}{T}.
$$

But what about other states? It seems like to define the entropy in this way for *any* possible equilibrium state we need to assume that any two such states are reachable from one another via a reversible process. Is this a realistic assumption? How can it be justified?

Comment: It applies to a pair of *thermodynamic equilibrium states,* not just any states.

Comment: @ChetMiller I intended to mean equilibrium states, clarified it in the question.

Comment: Try to provide an example of 2 thermodynamic equilibrium states of a material that cannot be connected by a reversible path.  Usually there are an infinite number of reversible paths that can connect the two states.

Comment: It seems this question was already asked in https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/263983/238271. 
Sorry for it, didn't lurk enough.

Comment: While the answers to that linked question approve this assumption have to be made, it's still unclear how to justify it as it's unclear why any quasistatic path in the (equilibrium) state space can be performed reversibly.